# Output a column from a SELECT using a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a variable named `$couponCode` where its value is from a textfield.

Here is the code to echo the value

```
  $couponCode = trim($_POST['p_code']);

  $coupons = $mcPromoCode->SelectPromoCode($db, $couponCode);

  $output = $couponCode;

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$output.'");</script>';
```

the SQL for Select

```
  public function SelectPromoCode($db, $couponCode) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
      "   SELECT coupon_code, coupon_level, coupon_days
          FROM `promocodes`
          WHERE used = 0 AND coupon_code = :coupon_code
          ");

    $stmt->bindValue(':coupon_code', $couponCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
  }
```

My concern is my output variable.

$output = $couponCode;

If I echo using that it shows the string from my textfield.

Now I also want to echo out my `coupon_level` and `coupon_days`

[image: 1]

I tried these: (one at a time of course)

```
$output = $coupons['coupon_code'];
$output = $coupons['coupon_level'];
$output = $coupons['coupon_days'];
```

But there is nothing in the echo when I am using this.

Comment: Not too sure about php, but you are trying to save `rowcount` in `$rows` variable. You should be saving the data using `fetch` ? instead you are saving rowcount ?

Comment: you are fetching the rowcount()? `$stmt->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the number of rows from your query. You should return the result set of query.

Below is the code

```
public function SelectPromoCode($db, $couponCode) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
      "   SELECT coupon_code, coupon_level, coupon_days
          FROM `promocodes`
          WHERE used = 0 AND coupon_code = :coupon_code
          ");

    $stmt->bindValue(':coupon_code', $couponCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```